# Rmove xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am trying to remove the attribute `xmlns="http://webdev2003.test.com"` from the following xml using xsl/xslt, a requirement of the XML Task in SSIS.  What is a proper methodology considering a large file size. ~40mb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfAccount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
<Account>  
    <FirstName xmlns="http://webdev2003.test.com/">John</FirstName>  
    <LastName xmlns="http://webdev2003.test.com/">Smith</LastName>  
</Account>  
</ArrayOfAccount>
```

Comment: Is there no proper namespace handling in SSIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate when I answer my own questions, but the credit goes to - http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2003/06/13/8679.aspx

The first part of the example lists how to remove all attributes which in my scenario works.  Perhaps there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the namespace declarations as described in [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/index.html). It looks like you might have to declare a prefix for the namespace in your stylesheet before adding it to the exclude-result-prefixes attribute.

> You can prevent this from happening with the xsl:stylesheet element's exclude-result-prefixes attribute. This attribute's name can be confusing, because the namespace prefixes will still show up in the result tree. It doesn't mean "exclude the prefixes in the result"; it means "exclude the namespaces with these prefixes".

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute::*"/>
      <xsl:if test="namespace-uri()!='http://webdev2003.test.com/' and
              namespace-uri()!=''">
        <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">
          <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

?

Comment: I get an error from XML Notepad - An attribute with a local name 'xmlns' and a null namespace URI cannot be created.  Respectively in MSVS error: An attribute with a local name 'xmlns' and a null namespace URI cannot be created.